# How to test import image into cloudinary with django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, cloudinary

I started creating django unit tests for my project referring to [the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/). But in my case I can't find documentation on how to test an upload of a picture into cloudinary, how to know if the import is succeeded.

I have created this unit test to test the  upload of a  picture :

```
    def test_upload_profile_picture(self):
        url = self.reverse('save_profile_picture')
        img = '/images/img.jpg'
        self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        with open(img, 'rb') as infile:
        response = self.client.post(url, {'picture': infile})
        self.assertRedirects(response, self.reverse('edit_profile'))
```

But I guess this is not correct since I really don't know if the image is really uploaded to cloudinary or not .

Has someone an idea about how to do this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, this test should be done by Cloudinary. It is like testing if Django actually saves the instance of the model. Nonetheless, you probably should use `mock` and make sure that the mocked resource is called, like in the relevant [Coudinary tests](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/e2646b9933d234eea9dda3355025c3f082b1795e/django_tests/test_cloudinaryField.py#L40-L49).

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/master/samples/basic/basic.py) provided by cloudinary, you can find some examples about how to upload photo to cloudinary and GETTING RESPONSE afterwards. For doing that you need to install cloudinary.

Cloudinary also provides you buildin models for django. You can import them by putting .
`from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField`.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = CloudinaryField(u'Cloudinary Image',blank=True,null=True)
```

or you can define your own upload options by doing;

```
class OtherCloudinaryField(CloudinaryField):
    def upload_options(self, model_instance):
        return {
            'unique_filename': True,
            'resource_type': 'image',
            'width': 1024,
            'height': 768,
            'format':'png',
            'tags': [model_instance.user.email],
            'invalidate': True,
            'quality': 95,
        }
```

Then use it for your model;

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        image = OtherCloudinaryField(u'Cloudinary Image',blank=True,null=True)
```

If you put cloudinary settings to `settings.py`, when you upload photo to a model, it will be directly uploaded to your cloudinary account and link of this photo will be saved to your attribute.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I have already defined my image field as a  cloudinary field in my User model .. my question is about is there a way to create a django unit test for uploading images into cloudinary.